Is there a way to use the Python SDK to implement hybrid search + semantic reranking in AzureAI search?
As implied by this article: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ai-azure-ai-services-blog/azure-cognitive-search-outperforming-vector-search-with-hybrid/ba-p/3929167 it is possible to perform a hybrid search with semantic re-ranking over the result set. However, I have been unable to implement these together in the python SDK. If parameters for both are set, semantic will take precedence.
The code snippet below works, but as mentioned, this will only perform a semantic search (i.e. will return the same search results if I remove vector_queries from client.search(). Similarly, removing query_type, semanic_configuration_name, and query_answer allows me to perform a hybrid search. However, I want to perform both.
        vector = embedding_client.embeddings.create(input = [name], model="embedding").data[0].embedding
        vector_query = VectorizedQuery(vector=vector,k_nearest_neighbors=4,fields="contentVector")
        credential = AzureKeyCredential(key)
        client = SearchClient(endpoint=service_endpoint,
                      index_name=index_name,
                      credential=credential)
        results = client.search(search_text=name, 
                                vector_queries=[vector_query],
                                query_type="semantic",
                                semantic_configuration_name = "azureml-default",
                                query_answer="extractive",
                                top = 4 
                                )

Does such functionality exist in the SDK? I have attached a screenshot of the implementation using the REST api.
REST api implementation

The document says it is best practice to give the semantic ranker the maximum number of documents that is 50.

it's smart to give the semantic ranker the maximum number of documents (50).

So, you change your code like below by giving k=50 and taking top 50 results.
    vector_query = VectorizedQuery(vector=get_embeddings(query), k_nearest_neighbors=50, fields="text_vector")


    semantic_search_results = search_client.search(
        search_text=query,
        vector_queries=[vector_query],
        select=["title", "chunk"],
        query_type="semantic",
        semantic_configuration_name="vector-1721991000151-semantic-configuration",
        top=50
    )


Next, i got results for both semantic and hybrid using below code.
def semantic_hybrid_search(query):
    

    search_client = SearchClient(service_endpoint, index_name, AzureKeyCredential(key))
    vector_query = VectorizedQuery(vector=get_embeddings(query), k_nearest_neighbors=50, fields="text_vector")


    semantic_search_results = search_client.search(
        search_text=query,
        vector_queries=[vector_query],
        select=["title", "chunk"],
        query_type="semantic",
        semantic_configuration_name="vector-1721991000151-semantic-configuration",
        top=50
    )

    hybrid_search_results = search_client.search(
        search_text=query,
        vector_queries=[vector_query],
        select=["title", "chunk"]
    )

    
    
    print("hybrid search results-----------------------")
    for result in hybrid_search_results:
        a = result['title']
        c = result["@search.reranker_score"]
        d = result['@search.score']
        print(f'{a} :   {c} :   {d}')

    print("\n")
    print("semantic search results-----------------------")
    for result in semantic_search_results:
        a = result['title']
        c = result["@search.reranker_score"]
        d = result['@search.score']
        print(f'{a} :   {c} :   {d}')


And output:
hybrid search results-----------------------
78776426_7_24_24.html :   None :   0.03333333507180214
78750167_7_22_24.html :   None :   0.03226646035909653
78782543_7_23_24.html :   None :   0.03201844170689583
Azure Search Index VIA .NET Core console app, over-writes old document.html :   None :   0.03128054738044739
78776426_7_24_24.html :   None :   0.031054403632879257
78781003_7_24.html :   None :   0.03077651560306549
Azure Search Index VIA .NET Core console app, over-writes old document.html :   None :   0.03076923079788685
78783121.html :   None :   0.03057890012860298
78783121.html :   None :   0.02921108715236187
Azure Search Index VIA .NET Core console app, over-writes old document.html :   None :   0.028991596773266792
78783121.html :   None :   0.028985507786273956


semantic search results-----------------------
78776426_7_24_24.html :   3.254748821258545 :   0.03333333507180214
78776426_7_24_24.html :   2.1206436157226562 :   0.031054403632879257
Azure Search Index VIA .NET Core console app, over-writes old document.html :   1.555912971496582 :   0.028991596773266792
78783121.html :   1.5436580181121826 :   0.02921108715236187
Azure Search Index VIA .NET Core console app, over-writes old document.html :   1.4620863199234009 :   0.03128054738044739
Azure Search Index VIA .NET Core console app, over-writes old document.html :   1.4142156839370728 :   0.03076923079788685
78781003_7_24.html :   1.3766850233078003 :   0.03077651560306549
78783121.html :   1.3763020038604736 :   0.028985507786273956
78783121.html :   1.212775707244873 :   0.03057890012860298
78782543_7_23_24.html :   1.155330777168274 :   0.03201844170689583
78750167_7_22_24.html :   0.9561886787414551 :   0.03226646035909653


If you observe output from document 2 the ranking is changed and document 1 is common. This is because the hybrid search also gives you the equivalent results to semantic for some top documents based on your document data and chunking since the search query will be in the same document even it is split into chunks.
It is not like hybrid search should give always less accurate then semantic for top results.
The process is like first the result of hybrid search is merged and reordered by new search scores, using Reciprocal Rank Fusion (RRF) then these results are sent to semantic ranking.
When k=50 in hybrid query, and some top results from hybrid will still be in top after semantic ranking that is the reason you are getting the same for both the query.
So, fetch more documents to see the real difference between these queries.
